# Setter and Getter in .net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I was just trying to set up a small example program in .net core c# but always run into a problem with the setter and getter

```
      public int wheels {
                get { return wheels;}
                set {  wheels = value + 10; }
                }
```

Exception has occurred.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in core_app.dll

I mean, this is the way how you use it, right? When I just write set; get; it is working without any problem.

Comment: Watch the casing: exactly what are you setting/getting?

Comment: Oh man, sorry. I was pretty sure that in .Net Framework it was working like that. hanks